# Exposing a method with a return type of list in my C++/CLI assembly to my C# project

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI project that wraps a native C++ application, which I use in my C# project.  I added a few void methods in my C++/CLI class which expose correctly to my C# project.  The intellisense shows fine in C# and I can interact with the methods.  However, when I put a return type of a struct in C++/CLI, the method doesn't show as availible in C#.  Any ideas?

C++/CLI

```
IPFILTERINFOLIST GetBlockList()
{
   return _packetFilter->GetBlockList();
}
```

...which calls...

C++ Native

```
IPFILTERINFOLIST  PacketFilter::GetBlockList()
{
   return m_lstFilters;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  should create a "managed version" of the IPFILERTINFO struct and copy your unmanaged data into it. Then you create a normal .NET List<> and add all those managed objects to it.